# Finding the time of the computer going into hibernate mode

Tags: c#, wndproc

Is there anyway to find the time when the computer will go in hibernate mode with C#?

I've got the way to popup a `Messagebox` when the hibernate starts by using `SystemEvents.SessionSwitch` and `PowermodeChange`. The `Messagebox` only shoes when the computer actually goes into hibernate mode.

But I would like to know the time of it before it goes hibernate mode so that I can do execute something else before it goes to hibernation mode.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    switch (m.Msg) {
        case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
            switch (m.WParam.ToInt32()) {
                //value passed when system is going on standby / suspended
                case PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND:
                    MessageBox.Show("test);
                            break;
                //value passed when system is suspended
                case (PBT_APMSUSPEND): break;
                //value passed when system is resumed automatically
                case (PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC):
                    break;
                //value passed when system is resumed after suspension.
                case PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

I'm aware that PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND gets something when system is going on suspend but no message will popup

Comment: Looks like XY-problem to me. Why do you need to show a message right before your system goes to hibernate mode? Nobody will see it:\

Comment: @vasily.sib  they will see it when the system is powered on again.

Comment: then maybe you should show it when the system is powered on again?

Comment: a message show is just for testing.. I've got something else to do before the computer goes hibernate..

Comment: Hibernation is *not* the time to *start* new work. Rethink your design. Any time you're thinking of trying to do things at "close" events, try to find a way to restructure it to instead work with the corresponding "open" event.